# Angularjs ui router reject resolve how to avoid loading template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've got this code

```
//Setting up route
angular.module('my')
    .config(['$stateProvider',function($stateProvider) {
        //  Check if the user is just logged
        var checkLoggedOut = function($http) {
            /* if the user is just logged the server send a Forbidden status 403*/
            return $http.get('/loggedout');
        };
        //  Check if the user is logged
        var checkLoggedIn = function($http) {
            return $http.get('/loggedin');
        };

        // states for my app
        $stateProvider
            .state('user', {
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'users/views/index.html',
                resolve: {
                    loggedin: checkLoggedIn
                }
            })
            .state('user_register', {
                url: '/user/register',
                templateUrl: 'users/views/register.html',
                resolve: {
                    loggedin: checkLoggedOut
                },
                controller:'UserRegisterCtrl'
            });
    }
    ]);
```

if the user is just logged can't go to the state user_register

but the template is still loaded.

Is it the wanted behaviour ?

Is there a way to avoid it ?

### UPDATE

may be my question can be misunderstand

**I want to know if there is a way to avoid template loading if the resolve is rejected I mean all in all why on earth the template is loaded when the resolve is rejected imo if the resolve fails the template should not be loaded**

### END UP WITH

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q','$location',function ($q, $location) {
        return {
            'response': function(response) {
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    $location.path('/signin');
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
                if (response.status === 403) {
                    $location.path('/');
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            'responseError': function(rejection) {
                if (rejection.status === 401) {
                    $location.path('/signin');
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
                if (rejection.status === 403) {
                    $location.path('/');
                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }

        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, making a REST call to check if the user is logged in with every state transition may be expensive. It may just be better to store the state of the user in the browser.

Second, more to the question you are asking: you can create an event handler to listen for the $stateChangeStart event. In this handler you can check if the user is logged in and whether they would be able to access the state.

This link should help http://www.frederiknakstad.com/2014/02/09/ui-router-in-angular-client-side-auth/

Comment: mmm I'm not asking for how to do but why on earth if the resolve is rejected the template is loaded and if there is a way to avoid that sorry I gave you -1

Answer (score -1):

Your checkLoggedIn function must manage the case in which the user is not authenticated. It could redirect him to the corresponding state using $state.go() or $location.